# How to parse string to JSON with double quote, in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

My string is like this:

```
"{\"message\":\"Initializing ProtocolHandler [\"http-nio-8099\"]\" }"
```

It seems the `\"` surrounding `http-nio-8099` prevent parsing.

How can such a string be parsed into JSON in ruby? Or how can I process it before it can be?

This string is taken from the log of docker running on kubernetes. The original one is `{message":"Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8099"]"}`, and slash is added by docker.

Comment: That string isn't valid JSON, you'd have to try and fix the embedded quotes so that it looks like `"{\"message\":\"Initializing ProtocolHandler [\\\"http-nio-8099\\\"]\" }"` (or less noisy: `'{"message":"Initializing ProtocolHandler [\"http-nio-8099\"]" }'`). Where is that broken string coming from? Fixing the source to not produce garbage would be preferable.

Comment: I agree with @muistooshort, it seems to be a malformed json string.